# In Python, how to change the values in a tuple by assignment?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

I have some values in a list of lists that look like this tuple

```
print list_of_lists[0][0]

(1,2,'.')
```

I want to change the '.' to either a '+' or a '-' so that it becomes `(1,2,'+')` based on some conditions.

Currently when I do a simple
`list_of_lists[0][0][2] = '+'` I get an error:
`TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment` because tuples are immutable in Python.

What do I do?

Comment: Tuples can not be changed. Your only options are to replace it by an other tuple or to a list in the first place.

Comment: I tried a 
`lst = list(list_of_lists)`
`lst[0][0][2] = '+'`
`t = tuple(lst)`
This doesn't work either because of the nested nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(not a good solution)

```
>>>list_of_lists = [[(1, 2, '.')]]
>>>[[tuple(["+" if j=="." else j for j in i]) if '.' in i else i for i in list_of_lists[0]]]
[[(1, 2, '+')]]
```

Comment: Why is this not a good solution? Is it because it is not elegant?

Comment: Not optimized, just anwered thats why.Also `[[tuple("+" if j=="." else j for j in i) if '.' in i else i for i in list_of_lists[0]]]` is little bit optimized